# If product variation contains this phrase, then do this

Tags: php, woocommerce, conditional-statements, product-variations

Edited: Problem: Force Sells plugin quantity needs to vary based on the quantity of the item added to the cart OR it needs to vary based on the selected variation (pa_size).

In other words, we are trying to force sell Ice Packs. If the customer buys less than 4(quantity) products, we want to force sell 1 ice pack. If they buy 8 (quantity) products, we want to force sell 2 ice packs. AND, if they purchase 1 (quantity) of a 6 Pack, we want to force sell 2 ice packs. AND, if they purchase 1 (quantity) of a 12 Pack, we want to force sell 3 ice packs. For everything else, force sell 1 Ice Pack.

I would really love to learn how to pull this off.

I need the variable $quantitybj to be the result because it is being passed by more code further down.

The output I get now is $quantitybj = 3 -- regardless.
The output I expect is that $quantitybj varies depending on quantities and selected product variation (ie. a 6 pack of cookies as opposed to one package of cookies).

I have commented out the errors in the code below.

$product_size *should* be a string and then I am trying to see if that string contains the words "6 pack" or "12 pack". How do I get the selected variation to make that comparison?

This is the full function from the woocommerce-force-sells.php. 
The code i added is commented out with BJ -- just so you know what I've added.

```
    echo '<pre><code>', print_r($product->get_available_variations()), '</code></pre>'; exit();

                        public function add_force_sell_items_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {
        // Check if this product is forced in itself, so it can't force in others (to prevent adding in loops)
        if ( isset( WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['forced_by'] ) ) {
            $forced_by_key = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['forced_by'];

            if ( isset( WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $forced_by_key ] ) ) {
                return;
            }
        }

        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        $force_sell_ids = array_filter( $this->get_force_sell_ids( $product_id, array( 'normal', 'synced' ) ), array( $this, 'force_sell_is_valid' ) );
        $synced_ids     = array_filter( $this->get_force_sell_ids( $product_id, array( 'synced' ) ), array( $this, 'force_sell_is_valid' ) );



        // BJ - CHANGE THE QUANTITY OF ICE PACKS TO EXACTLY HOW MANY IS NEEDED DEPENDING ON THE ORDER //



        //This part is working
        $quantitybj = '1';

        if ($quantity > '4') {
            $quantitybj = '2';
        }
        if ($quantity > '8') {
            $quantitybj = '3';
        }

        // this part is not working. I am attempting to say "if the selected variation CONTAINS the string "6 Pack", then $quantitybj = something new. 

        // FIRST PROBLEM: I get an error "Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/mfpnuts/public_html/novo/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-force-sells/woocommerce-force-sells.php on line 

        //SECOND PROBLEM: $quantitybj passes as "3" regardless of the option chosen.


        $product_size = $product->get_available_variations();

        if(strpos( $product_size, '6 Pack') !== FALSE ){
            $quantitybj = '2';
        }
        if (strpos( $product_size, '12 Pack') !== FALSE ){
            $quantitybj = '3';
        }


        // END BJ EDITS FOR QUANITY -- more edits on lines 390 & 400


        if ( ! empty( $force_sell_ids ) ) {
            foreach ( $force_sell_ids as $id ) {
                $cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $id, '', '', array( 'forced_by' => $cart_item_key ) );
                $key = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_id );

                if ( ! empty( $key ) ) {
                    WC()->cart->set_quantity( $key, WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $key ][$quantitybj ] );
                } else {
                    $args = array();

                    if ( $synced_ids ) {
                        if ( in_array( $id, $synced_ids ) ) {
                            $args['forced_by'] = $cart_item_key;
                        }
                    }

                    // BJ changed "$quantity" to "$quantitybj"

                    $params = apply_filters( 'wc_force_sell_add_to_cart_product', array( 'id' => $id, 'quantity' => $quantitybj, 'variation_id' => '', 'variation' => '' ), WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ] );
                    $result = WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $params['id'], $params['quantity'], $params['variation_id'], $params['variation'], $args );

                    // If the forced sell product was not able to be added, don't add the main product either. "Can be filtered"
                    if ( empty( $result ) && apply_filters( 'wc_force_sell_disallow_no_stock', true ) ) {
                        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
                        throw new Exception( sprintf( __( '%s will also be removed as they\'re sold together.', 'woocommerce-force-sells' ), $product->get_title() ) );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you also add example data of $quantity, product size and variation_attribute? Also specify the output you get now and the ouput you want/expect. This way we can get a clearer view of your problem

Comment: Have you tried [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)? Also do what @SvenHakvoort mentioned. You'll get way more precise answers that way.

Comment: Thank you so much... I changed it and added the full function so you can see how the info is being passed.

Comment: @BJBowen - The result of the `get_available_variations` function is not a String my guess is that it is returning an array. With that being said, what is it that you're trying to do with the `strpos` function?

Comment: @David -- You are correct. I want to get the variation that has been selected (6 Pack) and see if that string contains the phrase "6 Pack". IF it does, then do this. How do I get the selected variation to make the comparison? Thanks so much!

Comment: @BJBowen - Could you update your post to include the result of the following line: `echo '<pre><code>', print_r($product->get_available_variations()), '</code></pre>'; exit();`

Comment: Ok... I did that

Comment: And, yes, that pulls all of the info about any available variation for that product. I want to get the attribute_pa_size of the SELECTED variation --as a string -- and compare that to see if it *contains* the phrase "6 Pack".

If it *does* contain that phrase, then I'd like to do something. :-)

Comment: or maybe I want to get the terms of the selected variation?? Thanks

Comment: @David -- I updated the post with the code you suggested on the website and just now thought that maybe you wanted me to update it in my question above. Not sure, but I stuck it in there.

Comment: @BJBowen - I didn't need you to update the code, rather I needed you to update the post to show the results of that particular line of code.

Comment: @David - the code printed all of the information about all of the product variations, not just the variations that were selected or "added to the cart". So, as I've looked into this further, I need to get the name of the variation that has been added to the cart. Then, compare that string to see if it contains "6 Pack."

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you need a few conditional statements, one to check if the quantity is 1, another to check if the quantity is 4 or more, another to check if the quantity is 8 or more, and another to check the size of the packs.

Take a look at this example, I've commented the code heavily in the hopes that you can easily follow it:

```
<?php

// Declare the sizes of the packs, get a random number between 1-8, and then a random pack size
$sizes = array("6 pack", "12 pack", "18 pack", "24 pack", "30 pack");
$quantity = rand(1, 8);
$product_size = $sizes[rand(0, count($sizes) - 1)];

// Print the quantity and pack size
echo $quantity, ' cases of ', $product_size, 's';

// The default number of ice packs is 1
$ice_packs = 1;
if ($quantity === 1) {
    // if the quantity is 1 and it is a 6 pack, then add an aditional ice pack
    // if the quantity is 1 and it is a 12 pack, then add one more addtional ice pack
    if ($product_size === "6 pack") {
        $ice_packs++;
    } elseif ($product_size === "12 pack") {
        $ice_packs += 2;
    }
} else {
    // if the quantity is 4 or more then add an additional ice pack
    // if the quantity is 8 or more then add one more additional ice pack
    if ($quantity > 3) {$ice_packs++;}
    if ($quantity > 7) {$ice_packs++;}
}

echo '<br />Ice Packs: ', $ice_packs;
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/0NYrM)

Comment: Thank you David... Will you take a look at the code again? I have edited it so that you can see the full function and how the new quantity is being passed through as $quantitybj